# Почему z-index не работает при position:relative?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

У меня есть простенький слайдер. В первом случае, я использую `position: absolute`, во втором – `position: relative`.

***1. POSITION:ABSOLUTE – работает***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block_1, .block_2, .block_3 {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.block_1 > .block {
  background: red;
}

.block_2 > .block {
  background: orange;
}

.block_3 > .block {
  background: yellow;
}

.blocks-wrapper {
  width: 630px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#two:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#three:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-wrapper">
  <input checked type="radio" id="one" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-wrapper">
    <div class="block_1">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_2">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_3">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***2. POSITION:RELATIVE – не работает***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block_1, .block_2, .block_3 {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.block_1 > .block {
  background: red;
}

.block_2 > .block {
  background: orange;
}

.block_3 > .block {
  background: yellow;
}

.blocks-wrapper {
  width: 630px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#two:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#three:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-wrapper">
  <input checked type="radio" id="one" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-wrapper">
    <div class="block_1">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_2">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_3">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что при `position: absolute`, блоки изымаются из основного потока документа и накладываются друг на друга, располагаясь в одних и тех же координатах (если они не заданы явно, то это верхний левый угол ближайшего элемента с `position: relative`).

При `position: relative` блоки как бы приподнимаются над потоком. При этом, место за ними резервируется и продолжает оказывать влияние на другие элементы.

Исходя из вышесказанного, становится понятно, что `z-index` работает, но так как блоки располагаются за пределами родительского контейнера, который имеет свойство `overflow: hidden`, то эти блоки попросту не видно.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block_1, .block_2, .block_3 {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, background .5s;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.block_1 > .block {
  background: red;
}

.block_2 > .block {
  background: orange;
}

.block_3 > .block {
  background: yellow;
}

.blocks-wrapper {
  width: 630px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#two:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translatey(-100%);
}

#three:checked ~ .blocks-wrapper > .block_3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translatey(-200%);
}
```

```html
<div class="all-wrapper">
  <input checked type="radio" id="one" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="blocks">
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-wrapper">
    <div class="block_1">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_2">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_3">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```